# Remove certain characters from filenames

Tags: command-line, bash

I understand only a little about this. The below command removes the spaces from all filenames.

```bash
find . -type f -name "* *.*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0// /}"' {} \;
```

I would like it to also remove commas, periods and parentheses (  , `,`, `.`, `(` and `)` ), but I don't know where in the command to place the characters I want removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: the command
to remove spaces, commas, periods and parentheses
from a filename (in `$0`) is

```
mv "$0" "${0//[ ,.()]/}"
```

But don’t use that …

**Longer answer:**

- Your `find` command says `-name "* *.*"`. 
  That selects files whose names include at least one space
  *followed by at least one period.* 
  It makes sense not to try to process files
  whose names don’t contain space(s),
  since, if there are no spaces, there’s nothing to remove. 
  But I don’t know why that command is testing for period. 
  It will rename `fat cat.txt` to `fatcat.txt`,
  but would leave `hot dog` and `frank.fur ter` untouched.

  Since you want to rename files with periods in their names
  (to remove the periods),
  you should change your `-name` test to `-name "*[ ,.()]*"`.
- When you’re dealing with filenames that aren’t known in advance,
  it’s best to put `--` before the first filename. 
  It can be argued that this is not strictly necessary when you’re doing `find . … -exec …`, but it’s a good habit to get into.
- If you have files called `fat cat.txt` and `f a t c a t.txt`,
  they will both be renamed to `fatcat.txt`,
  and the second one will clobber the first one. 
  Passing the `-n` (no-clobber) option to `mv`
  will prevent this from happening. 
  But beware: it will leave files with spaces (etc.) in their names,
  and it might not even tell you that there was a problem!
- Your current command invokes a new `bash` process for every file. 
  This can make it take longer than necessary. 
  It’s preferable to invoke `bash` once and then invoke `mv` multiple times. 
  So, incorporating all of the above, we have

  ```
  find . -type f -name "*[ ,.()]*" -exec bash -c 'mv -n -- "$1" "${1//[ ,.()/}"' sh {} +
  ```

  But wait! 
  We’re not done yet! 
  Don’t use the above.
- When `find` executes a command (with `-exec`),
  it passes a pathname to the file to the command. 
  If you have a file called `fat cat.txt` in your current directory,
  `find` will pass `./fat cat.txt` to the bash command. 
  The above command will try
  to rename `fat cat.txt` (`./fat cat.txt`) to `/fatcattxt`. 
  If you’re running as root (i.e., `sudo`),
  this will move your files to the root directory, causing a big mess. 
  (Lesson: don’t run commands under `sudo` unless you’re sure you need it.) 
  If you’re not running as root,
  the ‘‘good news’’ is that the command will do nothing.

  So, now, putting it all together, we get

  ```
  find . -type f -name "*[ ,.()]*" -exec bash -c 'for f do dir="$(dirname "$f")"; base="$(basename "$f")"; echo mv -n -- "$f" "$dir/${base//[ ,.()]}"; done' sh {} +
  ```

  Note that I included an `echo` command in the above,
  as a “look before you leap” measure. 
  If you run the above command,
  it will show you all the `mv` commands that are needed. 
  If it looks OK to you, run the command again with the “`echo`” removed.

---

By the way, the command you show in the question will fail
if any files with a **`.`** in their name
are in a directory that has a space in its name.